# Doubt about proof of completeness

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let me refer you to:

http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/atm/caag1/balwant.pdf

Part (2) line $4$ can someone please explain why $x_{ni}=x_{n(m)i}$ for all $i \leq m$ and $n \geq n(m)$. I know it should follow by the fact that $n(m+1) \geq n(m)$ for every $m$ but I'm confused with this part.

Comment: please specify the notations

Comment: Shouldn't you ask this as a comment to that post since the issue seems to be that you don't understand something that was posted there? A completely separate post, one in which you moreover **omit** all the relevant information, is not the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $x_{n+1}-x_n\in\widehat{M}_m$ for all $n\ge n(m)$, so $$x_{n+1,i}=x_{n,i}\text{ for all }i\le m\text{ and }n\ge n(m)\;.\tag{1}$$ Suppose that $x_{n(m)+k,i}=x_{n(m),i}$ for all $i\le m$; then $x_{n(m)+k+1,i}=x_{n(m)+k,i}=x_{n(m),i}$ for all $i\le m$, by $(1)$ and the induction hypothesis. Thus, $x_{n(m)+k,i}=x_{n(m),i}$ for all $i\le m$ and $k\ge 0$, which is the same as saying that $x_{n,i}=x_{n(m),i}$ for all $i\le m$ and $n\ge n(m)$.

Comment: @user10: I don't immediately see any need for it. It comes for free, though, if we always choose $n(m)$ to be the **smallest** non-negative integer such that $x_{n+1}-x_n\in\widehat{M}_m$ for all $n\ge n(m)$, since $\widehat{M}_{m+1}\subseteq\widehat{M}_m$ for all $m$.

Comment: why is $x' \in \hat{M}$?

Comment: @user10: For each $m$ we have $x'_m=x_{n(m),m}\in M/M_m$, so we just have to check that $x'_m=\eta_{k,m}(x'_k)$ for all $k\ge m$. But $\eta_{k,m}(x'_k)=\eta_{k,m}(x_{n(k),k})=x_{n(k),m}$, since $x_{n(k)}\in\widehat{M}$, and $x_{n(k),m}=x_{n(m),m}=x'_m$, since $n(k)\ge n(m)$. (And that's why we need the inequality that you asked about in your first comment; I didn't notice this before.)

Comment: @user10: It's a little clumsier than necessary, but yes, it works. I'd say at the second stage that there is some $N(2)$ such that $x_{n+1}-x_n\in\widehat{M}_2$ for all $n\ge N(2)$, and we set $n(2)=\max\{n(1),N(2)\}$. In general, at stage $m>1$ there is $N(m)$ such that $x_{n+1}-x_n\in\widehat{M}_m$ for all $n\ge N(m)$, and we set $n(m)=\max\{n(m-1),N(m)\}$. Then there's no need to rename the sequence.